# java.io.IOException: exceeded maximum number of redirects: 20 in jmeter while replying

Tags: json, jmeter

While replying my script I am getting the below error. There is no correlation and I have changed the httpsampler.max_redirects=20 in jmeter.properties file.

But I get no result.. please help..

Comment: errror is java.io.IOException: Exceeeded maximum number of redirects: 20
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.followRedirects(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1435)
 at

Comment: Most likely means that whatever your test is doing causes an endless redirect on the server, which is quite a common bug. Run test with View Results Tree and see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

This error is noticed because JMeter allows maximum 5 redirects by default and your system may be using more than 5 redirects. You need to increase this count to more than 5 in jmeter.properties file. Follow below steps to achieve this.

1. Navigate to /bin directory of your JMeter installation.
2. Locate jmeter.properties file and open it in any editor.
3. Search for “httpsampler.max_redirects” property in opened file.
4. Uncomment the above property by removing # before it.
5. Change to value to more than 5 Eg. 20.
6. Save the file and restart JMeter.